# Angular Dropdown Not able to close when I'm clicking outside

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a angular date range picker. But I'm facing a problem. I'm not able to close the dropdown. I'm sharing my code below.

daterangepicker.html

```
<form formGroup="dateForm">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Start Date" formControlName="start" [value]="startDate? startDate: ''">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Choose a date" formControlName="end" [value]="endDate? endDate: ''"
        (click)="toggleDropDown()" (blur)="closeDropDown()">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="d-flex" *ngIf="showDropdown">
  <mat-card>
    <p>Start Date</p>
    <mat-calendar (selectedChange)="updateStart($event)"></mat-calendar>
  </mat-card>
  <mat-card>
    <p>End Date</p>
    <mat-calendar (selectedChange)="updateEnd($event)"></mat-calendar>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

daterangepicker.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { MatDatepickerInputEvent } from "@angular/material/datepicker";

@Component({
    selector: "date-range-picker",
    templateUrl: "./date-range-picker.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./date-range-picker.component.scss"],
})
export class DateRangePickerComponent implements OnInit {
    events: string[] = [];
    showDropdown: boolean;
    dateForm: FormGroup;
    startDate: any;
    endDate: any;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dateForm = this.fb.group({
            start: new FormControl(),
            end: new FormControl(),
        });
    }

    toggleDropDown(): void {
        this.showDropdown = !this.showDropdown;
        console.log("clicked");
    }

    closeDropDown(): void {
        this.showDropdown = false;
        console.log("clicked outside");
    }

    updateStart(event: any): void {
        this.startDate = event;
    }

    updateEnd(event: any): void {
        this.endDate = event;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to resolve this issue. The dropdown is opening. But, everytime I try to pick a date, the dropdown is getting closed.

Comment: you are triggering, the onBlur event, when you click on anything that is not the input. 

You could make a custom directive to listen for clicks in the window. Alternatively, (click)="event.preventDefault()", on the calendar, might prevent the blur event.

Comment: @cnps will you help me. I'm not getting actually

Comment: I missed a part of the answer, it should be there now.

Comment: It's not working. event is not defined

Comment: forgot the $ infront of event, it should be (click)="$event.preventDefault()"

Comment: this is not working :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
if (document.getElementById('showDropDown')) {
        if (document.getElementById('showDropDown').contains(e.target)) {
          this.showDropdown = true;
        } else {
          this.showDropdown = false;
        }
      }
}
```

In HTML

```
<div class="d-flex" id="showDropDown">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Start Date" formControlName="start" [value]="startDate? startDate: ''">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Choose a date" formControlName="end" [value]="endDate? endDate: ''"
        (click)="toggleDropDown()" (blur)="closeDropDown()">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

I just place demo id. Place wherever you needed.